# How to create application for Mobile?

Tags: mobile-phones

I have to create a mobile installable/client application...and I dnt know nothing abt this..

what SDK,language should I use?? if this will in .net will be fine(optional)... any Ideas

Will really appreciate this...

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

First you will need to decide what mobile platform or platforms you want to support. Often your choice of language and toolset will be completely dictated by that. For example, if you want to write software for the iPhone, you will need to use Objective C (and use a Mac) while Android-based phones and BlackBerry devices require Java. Windows Mobile and Symbian devices natively support C/C++ and their own proprietary APIs but you can use frameworks like [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) to make things easier (and portable between the two). Windows Mobile in particular also supports lots of other platforms that run on top of the base OS, such as slightly limited version .Net or Java (but bring-your-own-JVM).

The one common denominator between them all is web applications. If you want a single codebase that will work everywhere and that doesn't use a completely proprietary toolset, you can build a web app.

Comment: Thanks Adam for your reply...
I have to create software for Symbian OS, one thing abt I am confuse still is in your answer you wrote abt Web app applications but I want to make application to be installed on mobiles..

Answer (score 0):

Programming languages: Objective-C, Java, C# .NET CF etc. It depends on what devices you application should be running.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual studio to target Mobiles have Windows Mobile OS or Windows CE or Pocket PC, for other OSs you have to see the SDK that the Manufacture company provide.

Answer (score 0):

I you got no clue to start with, I suggest you start with Java ME. Java Mobile Application is, in my opinion, the safest way to go for starters as they have the widest acceptance among mobile device platforms.

Good luck.

Comment: Ya I agree with you...so from where should I start I mean to download SDK, how to code with JME any link??? thank you very much for your reply..

Comment: You can start by getting the SDK here: http://java.sun.com/javame/downloads/index.jsp and depending on your preference you might want to use IDE to make things easier such as Eclipse (http://www.eclipse.org)

Comment: whats IDE? I mean whats purpose??? and If I am right i have to dowload this Java Platform Micro Edition Software Development Kit 3.0...

Comment: Integrated Development Environment (e.g. Visual Studio) to make editing the source code and building the application easier, but if you haven't got any experience with it, just about any text editor would do - don't worry. This place could be a good starting point I think:
http://developer.symbian.org/wiki/index.php/Java_ME_Quick_Start

Comment: No worries, anyway could you please mark the post as answer if you think it answers your question? Thanks.